# Get item at specific offset of QMap

Tags: c++, qt, qmap

I have a `QMap` that represents a database row. The items are indexed by column name:

```
QMap<QString, QVariant> mapOfItems_;
```

I then have a method to retrieve item by columnn name:

```
QVariant ImportDataSourceRow::byName( const QString& name )
{
    if(mapOfItems_.contains(name))
      return mapOfItems_.value(name);
    else
      throw NoSuchColumn();
}
```

I would like to also implement method to get item by column index (`0` for first column):

```
QVariant ImportDataSourceRow::byIndex( size_t index )
{
    // Now what?
}
```

How can I get the value at offset `index` from the map? Is `QMap` even guaranteed to be ordered as I need it to be?

Comment: `return *std::next(mapOfItems_.begin(), index);` ? (Note that it is linear).

Comment: Maps are not suitable for searching by index. That's why there is no corresponding API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associative (dictionary-like) containers such as `QMap` and `std::map` rarely provide sequential indexing as internally they are *typically* implemented as tree-like data structures (for example, [Red-Black Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)).

Notable exception is boost's [`flat_map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/container.html). It is implemented as a pair of contiguous arrays, where mapping of the key and value is expressed with array indices: mapped key and value have the same index. `flat_map` provides method `nth()` to access value by index:

```
boost::container::flat_map<std::string, float> geek_numbers;
geek_numbers.emplace("pi", 3.14f);
geek_numbers.emplace("e", 2.72f);
geek_numbers.emplace(
    "Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and "
    "Everything",
    42.0f);
auto 0th = geek_numbers.nth(0); // 42.0f
auto 1st = geek_numbers.nth(1); // 2.72f
auto 2nd = geek_numbers.nth(2); // 3.14f
```

`flat_map` "emulates" interface and behavior of the `std::map` and sorts elements by key. You can use custom predicates.

Note that standard containers are suitable only for simplest database-like usecases. In general, databases is a very complicated topic. There are entire [theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) being built about it. If your dataset is large and you need to perform complicated indexing and queries, think about embedding one of the database engines available (e.g. [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite), or other, more [heavyweight ones](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html)).

Comment: In another answer, @tomáš-zato says that the column order is not by name. So this information would be lost when using a flat_map, right?

Answer (score 2):

The entries of a QMap are guaranteed to be ordered by key, in your case that'd be QString::operator<.

To get the position inside the map, you can use:

```
const auto it = mapOfItems.find(name);
const auto index = std::distance(mapOfItems.begin(), it);
```

Note that your byName() method would be more efficient if you used constFind() and throw if the returned iterator equals mapOfItems.constEnd(), instead of doing two lookups (contains and value()).

Comment: I guess I can't use `QMap` then, since the column order is not by name. Thanks for answer. Could you recommend what should I use instead? Maybe two arrays - names and values?

Comment: If your list of items is not too big, an easy and fast way would be a QVector<QPair<QString, QVariant> > object, and for index access you can use at() and for name access you would have to iterate, but if the List is small, that would be acceptable.

Comment: or just use a vector with the entries sorted by column index. But then byName() would have O(n) complexity instead of O(log n).

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended, but you can try to do it this way:

```
QList<QString> list = mapOfItems_.values();
if(index>=0 && index<list.count()) return list.at(index);
return QString();
```

Don't know how it works with a QVariant though.